# Display text depending on the size of the screen

Tags: html, scroll, responsive-design, resize

I am making a website and it shows a certain amount of text. For example:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
>   imperdiet venenatis nulla, sed viverra arcu eget ornare. Morbi
>   commodo, ullamcorper nec neque egestas, est est iaculis massa, massa
>   metus et semper at purus. Etiam nisl sed sapien in dapibus aliquet.
>
> Etiam auctor dui quis. Nam et nisi viverra scelerisque freed. In hac
>   habitasse dictumst audience. Donec egestas pain at varius sagittis
>   urn. Enim etiam urn consequat et eget sollicitudin, sagittis in
>   ligula. Maecenas euismod, enim a dictum iaculis, enim vestibu turpis
>   sapien, non convallis my vitae risus libero. Nullam in egestas dui.
>   Etiam in wk erat, sit amet arcu ultricies.
>
> Maecenas quis turpis release, id condimentum neque. Aenean release
>   enim, tempus vitae lobortis sit amet, vulputate id augue. Lorem ipsum
>   dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "

If the user connects from a tablet, this text produces a scroll, but I would like this text to be paginated, 3 pages page 1 showing in each paragraph, for example.

What I want is to have a very long text stored in a database, a json, xml or whatever, and by device and the size of the screen, showing pages, and that there is no scroll.

¿Someone could help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use css media queries to determine styles for different device types/screen sizes: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks Ryet0, but use Responsive Design Web with media-queries, but what interests me is to display text in a device, and display the scroll. That is, the amount of text that should appear on the web, it is necessary and according to the device page. If I have a text of 20 paragraphs, as in a computer with resolution of 1200 appear 3 paragraphs, and 7 pages on an iPhone, a paragraph to 20 pages, ... Do not know if what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP-Mobile-Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect) to detect the tablet's user agent and display the appropriate content.